# How to find oracle forms dependency

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I have 20 forms which I want to find all the dependency of them, would you mind help me please?

For instance if these forms using same table show me a dependency among them.
**actually I want to do some major changes backend so I am worry it hit error.**

Is there any free software?

I found [this](http://www.rhea.be/Website/freedownloadlist.htm) but it is not working I am receiving an error..

my forms version is 6i.

```
 Program Dump: 17/11/2011 12:54:25 Error ID:
 8WHR2sgAEtLWMbuDUODvrAJFmxCc12MoH1iADR4kdqzqRDfJMKy2Yulm76jMX2BGUBLUbHiDG4Y=
 Main

 Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.    at
 System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly)    at
 System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)    at
 Rhea.LicenseKey.RunProgram(String site, String serial, Type
 mainObject)    at DependencySearcher.FrmMain.Main(String[] args)

 Program Dump: 17/11/2011 12:54:41 Error ID:
 8WHR2sgAEtLWMbuDUODvrAJFmxCc12MoH1iADR4kdqzqRDfJMKy2Yulm76jMX2BGUBLUbHiDG4Y=
 Main

 Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.    at
 System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly)    at
 System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)    at
 Rhea.LicenseKey.RunProgram(String site, String serial, Type
 mainObject)    at DependencySearcher.FrmMain.Main(String[] args)

 Program Dump: 17/11/2011 15:20:44 Error ID:
 8WHR2sgAEtLWMbuDUODvrAJFmxCc12MoH1iADR4kdqzqRDfJMKy2Yulm76jMX2BGUBLUbHiDG4Y=
 Main

 Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.    at
 System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly)    at
 System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)    at
 Rhea.LicenseKey.RunProgram(String site, String serial, Type
 mainObject)    at DependencySearcher.FrmMain.Main(String[] args)

 Program Dump: 18/11/2011 16:59:26 Error ID:
 8WHR2sgAEtLWMbuDUODvrAJFmxCc12MoH1iADR4kdqzqRDfJMKy2Yulm76jMX2BGUBLUbHiDG4Y=
 Main

 Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.    at
 System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly)    at
 System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)    at
 Rhea.LicenseKey.RunProgram(String site, String serial, Type
 mainObject)    at DependencySearcher.FrmMain.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: what sort of dependency?

Comment: I want to know which table is existing in them. I mean if two of them using same table show me a dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Forms API which allows us some programmatic access to the Forms source.  The original API, introduced in Forms 5.0, was written in C but Oracle did release a Java version of it.  I can't remember when that was, but it was available for Forms 6i.  Search your Forms installation for "jdapi".

The other thing you can do is run the Forms to XML converter.  This generates an XML version of the source, which you can then search for Table Names.

Sorry this is a bit vague, but it has been a decade since I last used Forms 6i.  Which reminds me, Forms 6i was a good tool in its day but its day was a long time ago, from the day when the internet was much smaller, online information is hard to find.  And of course it has long since fallen out of support.

Comment: We've used the XML conversion and standard grep tools successfully. Also, most names are stored in text in the FMB, so you can search there. That won't be perfect, and it will include some false positives (because of stored undo information) but we've found it useful for a quick check and less work than converting them all to XML.

Comment: Thanks guys I will try and inform u.

Answer (score 0):

[ODA - Orale Dependencies Analyzer.](http://samtrest.com) This tool gives all answers about Oracle form dependencies.